# Event Log analytics?

Tags: windows, event-log

My Windows Event Log is being spammed by the same entry over and over again (an authorized entry managed by my workstation's keepers).

I need to convey the frequency with which the entries are being written.  Is there a tool of some kind that will generate some kind of analytics on entries occurring in my event log?

Charts would be fine, but, at the least, something that tells me how many entries there are for a given source, ideally compared to counts from other sources that have put entries in the same event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working further on JNK's answer, [you could use Powershell for this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/04/10/chapter-17-processes-services-event-logs.aspx#event-log).

[With some Powershell Excel automation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx) I guess you could create a chart to show these rate(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can always export the event log to a text file and import into Excel.  It's not the prettiest method but it works and you have full control over the results.